# Program doesn't capture the key

Tags: c#, key

As the title say , my program have a problem. I made a function(a battle function, which the player writes in a `textbox` and press a button). After the battle is done, my program doesn't capture the pressed keys, unless i alt-tab and alt-tab again in the program. What i have to do ?

```
//capture key function     
private void joc_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F4 && e.Alt && permite_pasi == true)
    {
        enableClose = false;
    }

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right && permite_pasi == true)
    {
        step(6); //step() is the movement function
    }

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W || e.KeyCode == Keys.Up && permite_pasi == true)
    {
        step(8);
    }

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left && permite_pasi == true)
    {
        step(4);
    }

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S || e.KeyCode == Keys.Down && permite_pasi == true)
    {
        step(2);
    }
}

//movement function
public void step(int directie)
{
    if (directie == 6 && checkstep(directie) == true) { //checkstep() is a function which check the environment for obstacles
        if (check_NPC(jucator.x, jucator.y) > 0) // function for checking the environment
        {
            scorenpc = check_NPC(jucator.x, jucator.y); //some variabile
            NPC(check_NPC(jucator.x, jucator.y), jucator.score); // the battle function
        }
        else
        {
            //movement instructions
        }
    }
    if (directie == 4 && checkstep(directie) == true)
    {
        if (check_NPC(jucator.x, jucator.y) != 0)
        {
            scorenpc = check_NPC(jucator.x, jucator.y);
            NPC(check_NPC(jucator.x, jucator.y), jucator.score);
        }
        else
        {
            //movement instructions
        }
    }
    if (directie == 8 && checkstep(directie) == true)
    {
        if (check_NPC(jucator.x, jucator.y) > 0)
        {
            scorenpc = check_NPC(jucator.x, jucator.y);
            NPC(check_NPC(jucator.x, jucator.y), jucator.score);
        }
        else
        {
            //movement instructions
        }
    }
    if (directie == 2 && checkstep(directie) == true)
    {
        if (check_NPC(jucator.x, jucator.y) != 0)
        {
            scorenpc = check_NPC(jucator.x, jucator.y);
            NPC(check_NPC(jucator.x, jucator.y), jucator.score);
        }
        else
        {
            //movement instructions
        }
    }
}
```

I'll put the rest of the code in a next edit if it will be neccesary.

Comment: Which kind of control your _label_ (guess joc) is? Has it the focus? If another control will receive focus then it won't get key events.

Comment: Are you sure those boolean statements do what you want? (true || false && false) == true, but (false || true && false) == false.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti is a `textbox`, sorry

Comment: @PrestonGuillot yes, i'm sure, i mean if they didn't do what i want, why they work after i alt-tab ?

Comment: Because you haven't tested a case where `permite_pasi` is false.

Comment: `permite_pasi` value is not modified for this part of code, and he is declared true

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, thank you. I use an `this.Focus()` after i exit the battle, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

At the ending of the battle function, i use an `this.Focus()`.